# Extract values from different subelements using XPATH

Tags: xml, bash, ubuntu, xpath

Currently I'm facing a xml file which basically looks like the following but with thousands of elements:

> ```
> <Data>
>     <Elements>
>       <Element>
>         <Subentry1>Value1</Subentry1>
>         <Subentry2>MoreData</Subentry2>
>       </Element>
>       <Element>
>         <Subentry1>Value2</Subentry1>
>         <Subentry2>MuchMoreData</Subentry2>
>       </Element>
>      </Elements> </Data>
> ```

I'm using Ubuntu and would like to print each combination of the values Subentry1 and Subentry2. For the above-mentioned example the wished output is:

> Value1_MoreData
>
> Value2_MuchMoreData

After reading something about XPATH string-join functions and trying endless ubuntu tools which do not support XPATH 2.0 I end up with the following working solution (bash script):

```
totalNumber=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//Element)' example.xml)
i=1
while [ $i -le $totalNumber ]
do
   xmllint --xpath "concat((//Element)[$i]/Subentry1/text(),'_',(//Element)[$i]/Subentry2/text())" example.xml
   echo -e "" 
   let i=$i+1
done
```

However, this is way to slow if you want to process e.g. 10000 elements. I would be happy if some expert can give me hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php), you can do:

```
==> xml sel -t -m "/Data/Elements/Element" -v "concat(Subentry1,'_',Subentry2)" -n test.xml
Value1_MoreData
Value2_MuchMoreData
```

Comment: Perfect. This works and it's super fast now! Thanks a lot. 50k lines per 0.2 sec.

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel Haley's response seems a lot more concise than the suggestion I'm posting.  I'll need to look at xmlstarlet, it seems a lot tighter than XSLT.  Nonetheless, here is a solution using XSLT:

```
$ xsltproc template.xsl input.xml 

    Value1_MoreData
    Value2_MuchMoreData

$ cat template.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:template match="//Element">
  <xsl:value-of select="Subentry1"/>_<xsl:value-of select="Subentry2"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


$ cat input.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
  <Elements>
    <Element>
      <Subentry1>Value1</Subentry1>
      <Subentry2>MoreData</Subentry2>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <Subentry1>Value2</Subentry1>
      <Subentry2>MuchMoreData</Subentry2>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</Data>
```

Comment: xmlstarlet actually creates XSLT for you. If you add `-C` to the command line (`xml sel -C ...`) it will print the stylesheet that was used internally.

Comment: I'll be happy to never write any XSL again.  Now I've got to check out xmlstarlet.

Comment: Since the XSLT is generated, it seems over complicated to me. I prefer writing my own XSLT. I only use xmlstarlet to answer stackoverflow questions. :-) Hopefully you find it much more useful. +1